# Why my cpp code is showing segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I try to develop a solution to this given problem: This code is the solution to: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/tree-level-order-traversal/problem.

In short: I have to do a level order teversal of a tree.

Unfortunately, I have a segmentation fault error.

I have been debugging it but stuck! I can't find the problem.

**My implementation is the following:**

```
struct que{
    struct node *a;
    int cap;
    int front;
    int rear;
};
struct que* createq()
{
    struct que *q=(struct que *)malloc(sizeof(struct que));
    q->front=-1;
    q->rear=-1;
    q->cap=1;
    q->a=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(q->cap));
    return q;
}
struct que* resize(struct que* q)
{   q->cap=q->cap*2;
    q->a=(struct node *)realloc(q->a,sizeof(q->cap));
return q;
}
int isempty(struct que* q)
{
    if(q->front==-1&&q->rear==-1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
int isfull(struct que* q)
{
    if((q->rear+1)%q->cap==q->front)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
void insertion(struct que *q,struct node *n)
{
    if(isempty(q)==1)
    {
        q->front=0;
        q->rear=0;

    }
    if(isfull(q)==1)
    {
       q->a=(struct node *)realloc(q->a,q->cap); 
    }
    q->a[q->rear]=*n;
    q->rear=q->rear+1;
    q->rear=q->rear%q->cap;


}
struct node* del(struct que *q)
{
   struct node *temp;
    (*temp)=q->a[q->front];
    if(q->front==q->rear)
    {
         q->front=-1;
        q->rear=-1;
        return temp;
    }
    q->front= q->front+1;
    q->front=q->front%q->cap;
    return temp; 
}
void levelOrder(node * root) {

  if(root==NULL)
      return;
  struct que *q=createq();
    insertion(q,root);
    struct node *temp;
    while(isempty(q)!=1)
    {
        temp=del(q);
        printf("%d ",temp->data);

        if(root->left!=NULL)
            insertion(q,root->left);
            if(root->right!=NULL)
                insertion(q,root->right);
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve]. Just saying "I have a segfault" and dropping a bunch of code is not good enough for an answer, Stack Overflow is not a valgrind service. At least you can say "when calling this function with this input, I get a segfault" or something like that.

Comment: Normally, if you can localize the bug, you will almost know how to deal with it. Please don't paste lots of codes. Try to learn how to analyze bugs.

Comment: If your question is how to debug a segmentation fault, you'll need to tell us what debugger you like using.

Comment: C++? Are you sure?

Comment: `struct node *temp; (*temp)=q->a[q->front];`

Among other concerns, this is expected to crash... You are writing through an uninitialized pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
q->a=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(q->cap));

q->a=(struct node *)realloc(q->a,sizeof(q->cap));
```

Surely `sizeof(q->cap)`, which is equivalent to `sizeof(int)`, is not what you want here.

Also:

```
struct node *temp;
(*temp)=q->a[q->front];
```

You need to assign `temp` a value before you attempt to use its value.